# Hockey Shootout

Tags: probability, self-study

Suppose that hockey players score 32% of penalty shots. Assume that three penalty shots are taken independently of one another. What is the probability that the team makes all three shots?

Comment: Common goalie, among other things, renders that assumption invalid. Understanding that, and its consequences, is much more informative than a lame, pretend "real world" probability calculation.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: -1 because I believe this question should disappear (not much useful to people other than the original questioner). But to to still aid the questioner: check Bernoulli trials. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial

Answer (score 2):

The probabilities of independent events are multiplicative. So the probability of events A and B occurring is P(A)*P(B). The same idea can be extended to more than two events. Imagine that the first player's shot is Event A, the second player's shot is Event B, and the third player's shot is Event C.

Comment: Please be cautious about providing answers to homework-style questions. Our policy (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)) is to provide hints only. The OP won't learn anything if you do it for them.